# Adobe Premier CC - Farsi Titles are shown Separate and Reversed

Tags: title, persian, farsi, adobe-premiere

I am using Adobe Premier Pro CC v8 for subtitling a video clip in Persian. Texts in titles are shown as sequences of separate letters and are being typed in reverse. I used several Persian fonts and reduced kerning to 0, which did not help. I also tried copying text from Microsoft Word. No change. Persian texts are displayed correctly in Adobe Photoshop too. I could not find any other solution on the Internet. Is there any other way to solve the issue?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, is it that the letters are separate and you want them to be one thread?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Edit > Preferences > General (Ctrl + K)
2. in Type Section  set "***Choose Text Engine Options***" to "***Middle Eastern and South Asian***"

Answer (score 2):

Do these three steps:

1. Edit->Preferences->Graphics->Text Eninge->South Asian and Middle
   Eastern
2. Edit->Preferences->Graphics->Text Eninge->South Asian and
   Middle Eastern->Editing Text in Middle Eastern Languages->Default
   Paragraph Direction:Right to Left
3. Delete the already created text and create a new one. Now texts are ok for
   the `Right to Left` writings.

Answer (score 0):

I think Arman Nooshin's solutions is for Photoshop, and it works. But for Premiere Pro I'm still looking for a solution like this. What right now I'm doing is; do your text in Photoshop, then import your file in Premiere Pro project and you can easily edit it in Photoshop from Premiere pro.